# How do I export a df as.character in R?

Tags: r, text, export, data-munging

How do I export a data frame completely as.character in r? I have digits that need to be treated as text in large dataframes, and I'm using write.csv, but even though I imported digits into r as characters, they are exporting as numbers (not surrounded by"" when viewed in notepad) and are occasionally rewritten as, e.g., 1e-04 (for a small decimal value). This is for data munging, and I need stuff to stay as formatted (once formatted). Shouldn't that be possible with some form of "as.character" or similar?

Comment: `?format.data.frame` ? see especially the `scientific` argument ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it into a matrix. If there is at least one character column in your data frame, it'll coerce the rest to character to match, since you can only have on type of data in a matrix.

```
new <- as.matrix(old_data_frame)
```

If there are no character columns in your old data frame, do:

```
new <- matrix(as.character(as.numeric(as.matrix(old_data_frame))),
     ncol=ncol(old_data_frame))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you user the function

```
write.table(x, file= ,quote=TRUE ...)
```

anything that is a string will be quoted on output

Comment: thanks, but this one doesn't work... what R considers numerics are still exported without quotes.